# How to get sprint or iteration details of a project in rtc jazz using OSLC

Tags: rtc, jazz, oslc

Can any one help me to get the list of iterations and sprints in that and workitems in that sprint using oslc or REST call

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/113810/oslc-iteration-query-with-project-url) reports that querying iterations might be a bit tricky:

> For the purpose of obtaining iteration for specific development line. Reporting Rest I/F may helps.

https://clm.example.com:9443/ccm/rpt/repository/foundation?fields=foundation/iteration[developmentLine/name='RTC V4.0.6 Development']/(id|name|developmentLine/name)

> This yields some thing like:

```
<iteration> <developmentline> <name> <iteration>
    <developmentline><name>RTC V4.0.6 Development</name></developmentline>
    <id>Sprint 2</id>
    <name>Sprint 2</name>
</iteration> </name> </developmentline> </iteration>
```

> Unfortunately, iteration belongs to development line, so we have to query developmentLine using like:

https://clm.example.com:9443/ccm/rpt/repository/foundation?fields=foundation/developmentLine/(name|projectArea/name)

> For the brief introduction to reportable RestAPI, [refer to this web pages](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/ReportsRESTAPI).

https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/ReportsRESTAPI

> Good feature of this reports API is that we can query by name, not uuid of objects.

Answer (score 0):

There

I had also this problems solved by this way. Try it.
It returns list of Open Sprints. 
http://jira.address/rest/greenhopper/1.0/sprint/picker

If you want to search for closed sprints in the future, you can use the following parameter in the above call:

http://jira.address/rest/greenhopper/1.0/sprint/picker?excludeCompleted=false